# What are the three dangers that the offenders are warned? Matthew 5:22

Tags: matthew, jesus, judgement

Matthew 5:22 World English Bible

> But I tell you, that everyone who is angry with his brother without a
> cause shall be in danger of the judgment; and whoever shall say to his
> brother, 'Raca!' shall be in danger of the council; and whoever shall
> say, 'You fool!' shall be in danger of the fire of Gehenna.

What are the three dangers that the offenders are warned of? Matthew 5:22

1/ Danger of the Judgement.

2/ Danger of the council.

3/ Danger of the fire of Gehenna.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the activity appears - I stress _appears_ - to _diminish_ in severity as the punishment _increases_ in severity.

Answer (score 4):

Matthew 5:22 is written in parallelism.

> But I tell you that
>
> 1. everyone who is **angry** with his brother without a cause shall be in danger of the **judgment**
> 2. and whoever shall say to his brother, '**Raca**!' shall be in danger of the **council**;
> 3. and whoever shall say, 'You **fool**!' shall be in danger of the **fire of Gehenna**.

It poetically expresses

1. lower court
2. higher court
3. hell fire punishment

I do not think one should dwell on their differences. The lesson comes later on:

> 25 “**Settle matters quickly** with your adversary who is taking you to court. Do it while you are still together on the way, or your adversary may hand you over to the judge, and the judge may hand you over to the officer, and you may be thrown into prison. 26Truly I tell you, you will not get out until you have paid the last penny.

It is better to quickly settle matters outside the court system and stay away from prison and hell fire.